# Dropdowns: IF ANY dropdown=value, show div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, show

Basically whenever 'bfcn' is selected show BFCN
Regardless if next value doesnt equal BFCN, as long as one equals the value, continue to show the

This issue right now is whenever selection is made on either, it will hide the div.

if 'dropdown1 = bfcn' = SHOW DIV
OR
if 'dropdown2 = bfcn' = SHOW DIV

It need to keep the DIV show if ANY of the dropdowns equal BFCN

http://jsfiddle.net/SmokeyLlama/f375e6wv/1/

HTML

```
<select title="Select 1" id="select1">
    <option value="">Select an option</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="4">bfcn</option>
 </select>
 <select title="Select 2" id="select2">
    <option value="">Select an option</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">bfcn</option>
 </select>
 <p class="wireless" style="display: none;">BFCN</p>
```

Script

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('select').change(function(){
      if (($(this).val() == '4')){
        $('.wireless').show();
      } else {
        $('.wireless').hide();
      }
   });
 });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this I'd keep a variable which I'd update if any `select` has `val() == 4`:

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('select').change(function(){
     var show = false;
     $('select').each(function () {
            if ($(this).val() == 4){
         show = true;
           }
        });
      
        if (show){
            $('.wireless').show();
        } else {
            $('.wireless').hide();
        }
   });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select title="Select 1" id="select1">
    <option value="">Select an option</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="4">bfcn</option>
 </select>
 <select title="Select 2" id="select2">
    <option value="">Select an option</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">bfcn</option>
 </select>
 <p class="wireless" style="display: none;">BFCN</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`filter()`](https://api.jquery.com/filter/) to return collection of the selects that have that value and use the length to create a boolean for [`toggle(display)`](https://api.jquery.com/toggle/#toggle-display)

```js
var $sel = $('select').change(function() {

  var hasBcn = $sel.filter(function() {
    return $(this).val() === '4';
  }).length > 0;

  $('.wireless').toggle(hasBcn);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select title="Select 1" id="select1">
  <option value="">Select an option</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="4">bfcn</option>
</select>
<select title="Select 2" id="select2">
  <option value="">Select an option</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">bfcn</option>
</select>
<p class="wireless" style="display: none;">BFCN</p>
```

Comment: Have an upvote just for using `toggle` rather than `if (condition) show() else hide()` :)

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like below. Check the code for comments and let me know if you have questions:

```js
//Create references to our DOM elements
const containerEl = document.querySelector('#container');
const wirelessEl = document.querySelector('.wireless');
const selectEls = document.querySelectorAll('select');

//Check if one of the select elements has the required value onchange
const onChange = e => {
  const [select1, select2] = Array.from(selectEls);
  if (select1.value === '4' || select2.value === '4') {
    wirelessEl.style.display = 'inline';
  } else {
    wirelessEl.style.display = 'none';
  }
};

//Use event delegation, so we only have to add 1 event listner on the parent element
containerEl.addEventListener('change', onChange);
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <select title="Select 1" id="select1">
    <option value="">Select an option</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="4">bfcn</option>
  </select>
  <select title="Select 2" id="select2">
    <option value="">Select an option</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">bfcn</option>
  </select>
</div>
<p class="wireless" style="display: none;">BFCN</p>
```